# .mdf is too new (661) my database supports version 655

Tags: sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-express

I am using SQL Server 2008 express and i want to import .mdf and i get this error:
.mdf version is 661, your db supports the version 655

Which version is 661 and how to import it in sql Server 2008.

Comment: Could you please edit the title to refer to 655 instead of 665?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Install SQL Server 2008 EXPRESS R2. There is a bug in the Web Platform Installer and it still thinks EXPRESS R1 is the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to apply a service pack.  Check Microsoft Update.

Comment: hmm i have sp1. In company we have enterprise version with sp1 also but the same error. Any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

Version 661  sounds like the format used by server 2008 R2 so it looks like someone has installed the beta and then attached your DB to it.

See this link for some more details

http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/SQL-Server-2008-R2-bumps-the-database-version.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Express 2008 - like without any service pack? Try getting your hands on the latest express version (they did not get service packs, but new installers) and install that. Chance we talk about 2008 R2 express, which should run around somewhere as beta?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably selected the instance name on the dialog box that comes when you try to add a connection from the server explorer in VS 2010. Try giving only the server name and it should work.