# I have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed, but I still can't run the project and open the database because "the server supports version 655 and earlier."

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a database in my `App_Data` folder that was created using SQL Server 2008 R2.

When I try to view a page, I get this error message:

> The database 'C:\My Projects\NCPA\APP_DATA\NCPA.MDF' cannot be opened
>   because it is version 661. This server supports version 655 and
>   earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
>
> Could not open new database 'C:\My Projects\NCPA\APP_DATA\NCPA.MDF'.
>   CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
>
> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\My
>   Projects\NCPA\APP_DATA\NCPA.MDF failed. A database with the same name
>   exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC
>   share.

Here's my connection string:

```
<add name="NCPA" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NCPA.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2010 installed on my computer. I've searched this problem all over, and everything says "You need R2", but I already have it.

I've also seen that I need to check the SQL Server instance name by going to `Tools > Options > Database Tools > Data Connections`, mine just says `SQLEXPRESS`. Is that right? Should it be something else?

What do I need to do here? Is there something that I might not have installed? Is there a setting in Visual Studio that I need to change? I feel like every solution I've found is so vague, or the solution is something I've already done.

**EDIT:** Here's what I have if I start up SQL Server, and go to `Help > About`:

> Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - 10.50.1617.0
>
> Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools - 10.50.1617.0
>
> Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) - 6.1.7600.16385
>
> Microsoft MSXML - 3.0 4.0 6.0
>
> Microsoft Internet Explorer - 9.0.8112.16421
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework - 2.0.50727.4961
>
> Operating System - 6.1.7600

Comment: your configurations is correct, and i dont think theres a problem with the DB file, the problem is in the SQL server which has an older version than the one created by your DB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.mdf is too new (661) my database supports version 655](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462919/mdf-is-too-new-661-my-database-supports-version-655)

Comment: Not inclined to vote to close as duplicate, as this OP has stated that he has already installed R2. OP in linked question hadn't done anything of the sort prior to asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you may have installed SQL Server 2008 R2, are you sure you upgraded the *instance* you're using to R2?

Use the SQL Server Installation Center from your R2 media and the "Upgrade from SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2005, or SQL Server 2008" option to upgrade your `SQLEXPRESS` instance to R2.

Comment: That sounds like that might be the problem...I've already installed SQL Server 2008 R2, is there a way to upgrade the instance after the installation?

Comment: Indeed. As per my post, use the SQL Server 2008 R2 installer to do so. Instead of installing a new instance, choose the option to upgrade an existing one.

Comment: Okay, that's a step forward. But I went to the Installation Center and clicked the `Upgrade` installation, and a dialog popped up asking me to `Browse for SQL Server 2008 R2 Installation Media`. I'm not sure what file I should be looking for, I installed this a while ago.

Comment: Run the Installation Center from whatever media you got SQL Server 2008 R2 from; if it's a CD, pop the CD in and autorun it. If you downloaded it from the internet, run the `.exe` file you downloaded again. (You can redownload it if necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you really, really sure that the SQL Server you are trying to attach the database to is SQL Server 2008 **R2**?

Your error message says that your SQL Server only supports version 655, and everything I found concerning these version numbers said that version 655 is SQL Server 2008 (non-R2):

- [SQL Server: Attach incorrect version 661](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257684/sql-server-attach-incorrent-version-661/4258260#4258260)
- [SQL Server 2008 R2 bumps the database version](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/SQL-Server-2008-R2-bumps-the-database-version.aspx)
- [Cannot read SQL Server 2008 database - version increased to 661 from 655](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/f8f8db38-3c20-45e4-ae8b-4cc097eb7f0d)

If you really have SQL Server 2008 R2 and it still doesn't work, you'll probably have to  re-install the server, like raym0nd said in the comment to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782206/i-have-sql-server-2008-r2-installed-but-i-still-cant-run-the-project-and-open-t/6782231#6782231).

---

**EDIT:**
Steven, none of the numbers you posted is the "real" version number of your SQL Server.
You can find out the actual version number by running `select @@version` in a query window in Management Studio.
On my machine, `Help --> About` says `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - 10.50.1617.0` like on your machine, but when I run `select @@version` I get this:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)   Mar 29 2009 10:11:52
  Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) 
  on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

And here comes the weird part:
I am 100% sure that I installed SQL Server 2008 **R2** on my machine.
In fact, the SQL Server stuff in my start menu says "SQL Server 2008 **R2**" everywhere, and the `Help --> About` window that you mentioned has a huge SQL Server 2008 **R2** logo as well.

But according to [several](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-versions) [lists](http://www.sqlsecurity.com/FAQs/SQLServerVersionDatabase/tabid/63/Default.aspx) that I just found, 10.0.2531.0 is SQL Server 2008 SP1.
So my installation seems somehow messed up as well.
Strange, very strange...

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I edited my original post to include the component name and version information. Take a look and see if you see anything weird.

Comment: I'm seeing something weird on **my** machine - see above, I edited my answer as well!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your code is trying to connect to the database instance that was install with Visual Studio 2010 instead of the SQL Server 2008 R2 instance that you have installed.

Comment: Okay. So what can I do to change that? Is there a way to tell which one my code is connecting to?

Comment: The part of your connect string that says `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS` is telling it to use the one that came with VS2010. If you execute `select @@ServerName` in Management Studio it should tell you what instance name to use.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the similar issue, when trying to attache an .mdf files that was created on another machine running SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, to the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on my machine..

I did install 2008 (non-R2) and then 2008 R2 on my machine.

After spending hours googling to find a solution, eventually unsuccessful, I simply decided to download the installer SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-AU/download/details.aspx?id=30438) and run it again, hoping it would solve (Windows 7 64 bit)

On the installation Wizard under Installation, I selected Upgrade from SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008 and continued to press Next until it disappeared (Obviously you will have to wait until it finish processiong each step).

That's it. I was able to attach the same file..

Comment: @Bishan *Please* do not use code formatting to just highlight things; it should *only* be used for actual code. The way you have highlighted all these product names makes things harder to read!

Answer (score 0):

Download and reinstall the new [MS R2 SQL SERVER](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) , When Microsoft updates something, it doenst support older versions most of the time.

Comment: He said that he already have R2 installed. Are you suggesting that he should reinstall?

Comment: I had the same problem couple of months ago, I had R2 installed, but still didnt work, then I downloaded a fresh copy of SQL server and re installed, restarted my computer and it worked fine.

Comment: @raym0nd - there has to be an easier way than reinstalling SQL Server entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Here what worked for me without trying any updates!

1. From Visual Studio --> Server Explorer --> Add New Connection
2. Change the data source to *Microsoft SQL server*
3. Server name : My computer's name `or` localhost
4. At the drop down list choose the database you want

Everything works fine! No updates and no 661 problems!