# Attached ASPNETDB in ASP.NET project giving Error while opening

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, aspnetdb

I have attached ASPNETDB in my ASP.NET project. Snapshot is the error message that I got as soon as I try to open it in Server Explorer.[image]

I have ran aspnet_regsql.exe from this folder:
**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319**

I am using .NET 4.0, VS2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Version 655 is SQL Server 2008 and 661 is SQL Server 2008 R2. This question was asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257684/sql-server-attach-incorrect-version-661

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My instance SQLEXPRESS was not upgraded. That is what causing the problem.

So what I got from this is my Sql Server was R2 but instance was not upgraded.

This 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782206/i-have-sql-server-2008-r2-installed-but-i-still-cant-run-the-project-and-open?lq=1)
helped me sort out the problem.

Thanks.